# PHP Как разрешить получение данных файла только через функцию curl или file_get_contents или ajax запрос?

Tags: php, файлы, curl, file-get-contents

Через прямой доступ закрыть пользователю доступ к файлу, а через curl, file_get_contents, ajax разрешить получать данные с файла, подскажите?

Answer (score 0):

Можно смотреть заголовок `User-agent`, но его можно подделать.

Еще можно назвать файл 32a68c48-267e-4884-a2f2-97b316ec6305,
отключить автоиндекс для его папки и сказать название только самым близким.